# Which filesystems support hard links (rsync) to backup a Mac?

Tags: mac, backup, filesystems, rsync, hardlink

I want to make a **rsync**-style hard-link **backup** from **Mac** on an external hard drive, but I cannot decide for a file system. It should be (preferably natively) readable from other operating systems.

Which file systems do support hard links? And which file systems does *rsync* support (with hard links)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `rsync` will support any file system the underlying OS supports. As for your requirement, there are no really good answers, but I might suggest ext2 as an interoperable filesystem because support for it in Linux is (obviously) great and support for it on MacOS is not too bad (with fuse). But you didn't specify which "other operating systems" you need it to be readable from. I think that will make a big difference.

Comment: I was mainly thinking about Windows, but I guess Linux is fine, too...

Comment: MacDrive doesn't seem to support hard links. NTFS doesn't either, I think. Linux reads MacOS disks fine, including hard links, but if you want to read on Windows...